# Announce the sender of a new message in Mail

Tags: applescript, mail.app, email

I am trying to create a simple AppleScript that I can use with rules to announce the incoming sender of a message. I want it to say their name and not their email address as well. This is what I have so far and it works if a message is selected.

```
tell application "Mail"
set theSender to sender of item 1 of (get selection)
set theName to word 1 of theSender & " " & word 2 of theSender
say "Incoming email from " & theName
end tell
```

This kind of works but doesn't seem to work with a rule that has more than one action. If I set the rule to only run the AppleScript and nothing else, it works. However if I add an action to move the message to a specific folder, it will move it but without saying the sender name.
Any ideas what's going on or how I can fix this?

Comment: Well I can propose something to make you able to select the newest message that comes to your inbox. Are you interested and does it answer your question? I want to be sure before posting.

Comment: I am interested in this. However, I am really trying to understand why the Rule script to announce a new email works when it is by itself and why it doesn’t work if there is another action added to it. And possibly if there is a workaround.

Comment: Try replacing the second line of your code with ```set theSender to sender of the first message of mailbox "xxx1" of account "xxx2"```. Replace the xxx1 by your inbox name and replace the xxx2 by the name of your service (e.x. "iCloud"). What does it do?

Comment: Nope. That didn't work. The script I posted works as long as it is the only action in the **Rule**, but adding a **Move Message** action makes it ignore the **AppleScript**. I even tried creating two separate **Rules**, one that says the sender name (with the above script) and the second one that moves it. I placed the announcement rule _before_ the move rule and it still ignored the AppleScript. Very confusing.